# styled-components render unique CSS per iteration

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Currently I'm using styled-components to manage height based on screen size.  However, I'm having a problem because it's not evaluating each div individually.  All CSS is being rendered based on the maximum size.  This is making gaps between smaller items larger and throwing off the formatting.

```
export const ColumnContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 687.5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%

  @media (min-width: 768px){
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: ${px2vw(2)};
    width: ${px2vw(325, 768)};
  }
`;

export const CardBox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: ${px2vw(500, 500)};
  min-height: ${px2vw(200, 500)};
  padding-top: ${px2vw(20)};
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 3%;
  max-width: 102%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0px;
  flex-basis: 200px;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    width: ${px2vw(320, 768)};
    min-height: ${px2vw(200, 768)};
    padding-bottom: ${px2vw(20)};
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    width: ${px2vw(710)};
    min-height: 30vh;
    padding-bottom: ${px2vw(20)};
    height: 100%;
    flex
  }

  & > a{
    color:rgb(94, 92, 92, 1.0);
  }
  
  & > a:hover{
    color:rgba(94, 92, 92, 1.0);
  }
`;
```

### Desired Layout

[image: Desired layout]

### Rendered Layout

[image: Rendered Layout]

Is there anyway to tell styled-components that I want unique CSS for each object?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? As your question stands, it's going to be extremely difficult to provide any assistance.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that.  Added the individual components to the original question.